# Need magento Admin panel in German Language

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I want magento admin panel in German language, but not able to find the solution for the same. Can anyone helf me in doing that. My magento version is 1.4.0.1.

Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Get a translation from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/3) and install it. Then in admin login and choose German from the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to install [this nice extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Rico+Neitzel/extension/413/magento-community-modules--german-germany-language-pack) and nearly everything will be in German :-)